# Oracle Create Table Syntax (not null and default)

Tags: oracle, syntax

I don't see why Oracle accepts

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL)
```

but not

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1)
```

In my understanding the components NOT NULL, DEFAULT, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY.. don't have to be in a special order, or am I wrong?

Comment: order matters in SQL

Answer (score 4):

You understood it wrong.

[column definition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/column_definition.html) (from [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)) says that DEFAULT goes first, and inline constraint (which NOT NULL is) follows:

```
column [ datatype [ COLLATE column_collation_name ] ]
  [ SORT ] [ VISIBLE | INVISIBLE ]
  [ DEFAULT [ ON NULL ] expr | identity_clause ]      --> DEFAULT goes before ...
  [ ENCRYPT encryption_spec ]
  [ { inline_constraint }...                          --> ... incline constraint
  | inline_ref_constraint
  ]
```